# Cannot get to the title screen

Tags: tropico-5

On the PC version of Tropico 5, after I go through the launcher, the game gets stuck on the artistic Tropico 5 loading screen. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using steam, you may want to try a repair of your files. It may take some time, but in some cases this will work the best.

Maybe it's a kind of lag due to your pc power. Does your system meet the minimum requirements? Do you see a high pressure on memory, disc or cpu during this time (task manager)?

Comment: It's DEFINITELY not my PC. I have a Zotac GeForce GTX 970 Amp! Extreme with an 8 core i7-3820 overclocked and 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: Why do you use an 8-core instead of an 6-core with much more single-core power. I would suggest a bit more RAM. Anyway... Did you check the files? I can't say much about the requirements as I never take a look at them. I know that it can be buggy. I've encountered a GDDR memory pressure on my machine as I've loaded a bigger island which is completely builded. This may be some idea. But I would mostly think about a disc pressure (slow disk) or a broken file.

Comment: Anyway, can you monitor your cpu and co while your trying to start it?

Comment: overclocking is going to kill your machine btw